# sails js add a custom task

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I am trying to add custom task to a sails js application. accroding to the documentation I create files in the following way.
tasks/register/test.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['mochaTest']);
};
```

tasks/config/mochaTest.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('mochaTest', {
        test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                captureFile: 'results.txt', // Optionally capture the reporter output to a file
                quiet: false, // Optionally suppress output to standard out (defaults to false)
                clearRequireCache: false // Optionally clear the require cache before running tests (defaults to false)
            },
            src: [
                'test/bootstrap.test.js',
                'test/unit/**/*.js'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
};
```

I have written test cases inside test/unit folder. I can run these test using grunt mochaTest command. But using 'sails lift --test' command does not run the test cases. instead it just run the sails application. I also tried the following command. ()
    NODE_ENV=test sails lift
It also does not run the test cases. It just run the sails application. (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets/task-automation)
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the file "tasks/register/default.js" to have the following code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compileAssets', 'linkAssets', 'grunt-mocha-test', 'watch']);
};
```

then just launch the app with "sails lift"

Comment: Thank you for the answer ovidio4usa. as I said earlier I can run the tests by, 'grunt mochaTest' command. But I need to run the tests using a command like this. 'sails lift --test'. I don't won't to run the tests for every sails lift.

Comment: Ok, Why don't you script a command that runs the test with "grunt mochaTest" and then it lifts the app using "sails lift"? Something like a bash script, Powershell script or even a nodejs one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But in sails documentation it is mentioned that we can use like sails lift --test by adding a custom task name test.